# Using the output of awk as the list of names in a for loop

Tags: bash, awk

How can I pass the output of `awk` to a `for file in` loop?

```
for file in awk '{print $2}' my_file; do echo $file done;
```

`my_file` contains the name of the files whose name should be displayed (echoed).

I get just a

```
>
```

instead of my normal prompt.

Answer (score 1):

```
for file in $(awk '{print $2}' my_file); do echo "$file"; done
```

Comment: Hmmm...you were missing a semicolon.  I've added it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks or `$(...)` to substitute the output of a command:

```
for file in $(awk '{print $2}' my_file)
do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

The notation to use is `$(...)` or [Command Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

```
for file in $(awk '{print $2}' my_file)
do
    echo $file
done
```

Where I assume that you do more in the body of the loop than just `echo` since you could then leave the loop out altogether:

```
awk '{print $2}' my_file
```

Or, if you miss typing semicolons and don't like to spread code over multiple lines for readability, then you can use:

```
for file in $(awk '{print $2}' my_file); do echo $file; done
```

You will also find in (mostly older) code the backticks used:

```
for file in `awk '{print $2}' my_file`
do
    echo $file
done
```

Quite apart from being difficult to use in the Markdown used to format comments (and questions and answers) on Stack Overflow, the backticks are not as friendly, especially when nested, so you should recognize them and understand them but not use them.

Incidentally, the reason you got the `>` prompt is that this command line:

```
for file in awk '{print $2}' my_file; do echo $file done;
```

is missing a semicolon before the `done`.  The shell was still waiting for the `done`.  Had you typed `done` and return, you would have seen the output:

```
awk done
{print $2} done
my_file done
```

Comment: thanks for all replies but I still get >

for file in $(awk '{print $2}' my_file); do echo "$file" done;
>

Answer (score 1):

Using backticks or `$(awk ...)` for command substitution is an acceptable solution for a small number of files; however, consider using xargs for single commands or pipes or a simple `while read ...` for more complex tasks (but it will work for simple ones too)

```
awk '...' |while read FILENAME; do
  #do work with each file here using $FILENAME
done
```

This will allow processing to be done as each filename is processed instead of having to wait for the whole awk script to complete and allow for a larger set of filenames (you can only give so many args to a `for x in ...; do`)  This will typically speed up your scripts and allow the same kinds of operations you would get in a `for in` loop without its limitations.